AWS Device Farm cloud debugging Android Studio
Is it possible to connect AWS Device Farm to Android Studio for cloud debugging project? I tried to use this from web browser. I launched the real device Xiaomi 13

AWS Device Farm available to launch Settings on the device, that's was important for me, but I can't find how to connect this to Android Studio for debugging? Help me please, I need test and fix bugs on other Android device platforms. I don't have own farm devices unfortunately. That's really pain. Thanks!!!

Remote adb access seems to be not possible: https://repost.aws/questions/QUitFvIMf_TzO7R-XZMDEb3w/how-to-connect-via-adb-to-a-remote-session-android-device-on-aws-device-farm
